# Selenium + Jmeter for load testing

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, jmeter

I'm working with Jmeter for load testing using selenium web driver Java code. I have written java code in Eclipse. According to my code I have added some selenium .jar files ,Jmeter .jar files to my java project & I have run the Java code in eclipse and generated .class file of my class. Now I want to add this .class file to jmeter in the form of .jar file

Now I want to put this code in Jmeter using Java Request Sampler for this I have done like this:

1. I have changed my Java code .class file to .jar and place in Jmeter installation directory at lib/ext folder.
2. Now problem is where I have to place selenium .jar files, in my jmeter

I have also tried placing  all .jar files in `Jmeter/lib/ext` or `Jmeter/lib` 
if I have done like this jmeter is not working .

Comment: if you simply want to run selenium in parallel, you can have a look at the maven surefire plugin or run them in parallel with gradle. i dont think it is a good idea to mix selenium(a tool for integration tests) with jmeter ( a tool for load testing)

Comment: Thanks rtruszk,It's not like that I want to use just selenium script (java code) in Jmeter to do load test. I dont want to add selenium plug in to jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You should respective `.jar` file in `Jmeter/lib/ext` directory. Every additional java code which you want to integrate into JMeter should be part of `*/ext/` directory only